# How do is solve the problem with installing the node.js sqlite3 package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, npm

When I install the sqlite3 package for a node.js by `npm install sqlite3` in command prompt and Error appears,
to watch error press[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeW72.png)to show image
,this Error in below:

> C:\Windows\system32>npm install sqlite3
>
> npm WARN deprecated
> request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see
> https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 npm WARN deprecated
> har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
>
> > sqlite3@5.0.1 install C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\sqlite3
> > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
> node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403):
> https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-win32-x64.tar.gz
> node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@5.0.1 and
> node@14.15.4 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile
> with node-gyp) gyp ERR! find VS gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set
> from command line or npm config gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual
> Studio version 2017 gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running
> in VS Command Prompt gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find
> Visual Studio 2017 or newer gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio
> 2015 gyp ERR! find VS - not found gyp ERR! find VS not looking for
> VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8 gyp ERR! find VS gyp
> ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version: gyp ERR! find VS gyp
> ERR! find VS
> ************************************************************** gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
> gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++"
> workload. gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the
> documentation at: gyp ERR! find VS
> https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows gyp ERR! find VS
> ************************************************************** gyp ERR! find VS gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not
> find any Visual Studio installation to use gyp ERR! stack     at
> VisualStudioFinder.fail
> (C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
> gyp ERR! stack     at
> C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
> gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013
> (C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
> gyp ERR! stack     at
> C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
> gyp ERR! stack     at
> C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
> gyp ERR! stack     at
> C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
> gyp ERR! stack     at
> C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler
> (child_process.js:315:5) gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit
> (events.js:315:20) gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose
> (internal/child_process.js:1048:16) gyp ERR! System Windows_NT
> 10.0.19041 gyp ERR! command "C:\Windows\system32\node.exe" "C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
> "configure" "--fallback-to-build"
> "--module=C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3"
> "--module_path=C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64"
> "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=6"
> "--node_napi_label=napi-v6" "--python=/path/to/executable/python"
> "--msvs_version=2017" gyp ERR! cwd
> C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\sqlite3 gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4 gyp
> ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0 gyp ERR! not ok node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute
> 'C:\Windows\system32\node.exe
> C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
> configure --fallback-to-build
> --module=C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node
> --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64
> --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6 --python=/path/to/executable/python --msvs_version=2017' (1) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.
> (C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose
> (internal/child_process.js:1048:16) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at
> Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041 node-pre-gyp ERR!
> command "C:\Windows\system32\node.exe"
> "C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp"
> "install" "--fallback-to-build" node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
> C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\sqlite3 node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v
> v14.15.4 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0 node-pre-gyp ERR!
> not ok Failed to execute 'C:\Windows\system32\node.exe
> C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
> configure --fallback-to-build
> --module=C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node
> --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64
> --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6 --python=/path/to/executable/python --msvs_version=2017' (1) npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Windows\system32\package.json' npm WARN system32
> No description npm WARN system32 No repository field. npm WARN
> system32 No README data npm WARN system32 No license field.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! sqlite3@5.0.1
> install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build` npm ERR! Exit
> status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@5.0.1 install script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
> additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Amjad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-02-04T16_21_25_568Z-debug.log
>
> C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: Click on the explanation to show the image

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include an explanation HERE in the question. Providing a link is not sufficient, and will result in the question being closed.

Comment: @JordanKasper done

Comment: Okay... lots of problems here, but the first one is that you should not use npm inside of Windows\system32 to install sqlite... in fact, you should not install things into Windows\system32 period, at all, using npm. Go to the [SQLite web site](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) and download the package and follow install instructions. Separately from that, you could install the sqlite npm package INSIDE a Node.js project to be able to access sqlite from a Node script.